# Screenshot specific element with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot, selenium-chromedriver

NOTE: I am aware this question has been asked before a few times however I am having a problem that others seem to not be having.

Even though I appear to be getting the point of the element along with its width and height correctly, the final crop is incorrect. It is like the screenshot I am taking has different dimensions to the webpage. I am using the Chrome Driver.

This is my code for attempting to get a screenshot of the google logo image:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));
//Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage fullImg = null;
try {
    fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
} catch (IOException e) {

}
//Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();
//Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();
//Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth,
                eleHeight);
try {
    ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
} catch (IOException e) {

}
//Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("/Users/M/Desktop/stuff/logo.png");
try{
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
}catch(IOException e){

}
```

Here is my final logo image:
[image]

Here is what it should be getting (just as a png not as gif):
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting wrong image. Because for me the code works perfectly

Comment: Yeah I posted the image in the question. I've tried on several different elements too. It's really confusing me. Were you using Chrome Driver? What version of Selenium are you using? @Madhan

Comment: It is getting the right width and height it seems but it's like zooming on or something on the screenshot? It is like the point and width and height of the screenshot are not the same as the webpage.

Comment: Using Windows 7,Java 1.7.101,Selenium 2.53, ChromeDriver 2.21, Chrome 51

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have custom scaling on your operating system. I had the same problem using 125% scaling on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below screenshot for more details.

Go to your system settings > Search for the display > change the value of "Make Everything Bigger" dropdown to 100%. Then run the code again this will work fine for you.

[image]